# ¿Cómo me conecto a una base de datos oracle local desde un proyecto que está en un Docker container?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, oracle-11g

Tengo una api rest montada en Springboot, y esta está dentro de un contenedor docker, la cuestión es que quiero conectarme a mi base de datos local, pero no me conecta, sí alguien sabe qué puedo hacer, se lo agradezco

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  app:
    image: "bm_spring_boot:latest"
    build:
      context: ./BmApiRestV2/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: api_spring
    ports:
      - 8888:8080
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=system
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=root
    networks:
      spring-net:
        aliases:
          - spring-host
networks:
  spring-net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
```

`exception`

> IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=ZXya/2jARQOjulME/+D4hA==)

Comment: Poner el contenedor a usar la red del host? Así quedaría sin aislar. La [documentación oficial](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/) siempre es un buen lugar para comenzar.

Answer (score 1):

Ten en cuenta que docker y el contener tienen un red interna diferente a la del Host, por eso localhost te resolvería internamente en el contenedor, si quieres la IP para consultar el Host desde la version de Docker 20 para Windows se puede realizar cambiando localhost por `host.docker.internal`.

Algo importante a tener en cuenta es que esta solución es para Docker 20+ y la solución que te he dado funciona en Windows, Linux y MAC, pero para Linux hay que agregar unos parámetros extras al ejecutar el contenedor y para MAC solo funcionaria si Docker esta en modo desarrollo no en modo productivo.

Lo ideal es que tengas otro contenedor con MySQL y de esta forma conectar el contenedor del aplicativo con el contenedor de MySQL.

Comment: Te agradezco por la respuesta, pero por alguna razón sigo sin conseguir conectarlo